# what is the maximum number of roots of quadratic function with 3 variables?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratic-forms

Given the general quadratic form with 3 variables $(x,y,z)$:

$ax^2 + by^2 +cz^2 + dxy + eyz +fzx + gx + hy + iz = 0$ satisfies $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$

I would like to ask what is the maximum number of roots of the provided equation. Do you know how to count the number of roots of quadratic form with n variables?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is not about roots, but about components of intersection, between two quadrics. When you ask this question at MSE, you should make correction.

Comment: thank you for your comments

Comment: Consider the case when $i=1$ and all the other coefficients are equal to zero. The first equation boils down to $z=0$, producing infinitely many solutions of the form $(x,y,z)=(\cos t,\sin t, 0)$ for $t\in [0,2\pi)$. Thus, the "maximum number" is "infinity".